# Segmentation Fault after accessing node

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a random deck of cards using a linked list. However, whenever I try to use my addCard function I get a segmentation fault error.

Is temp->card->suit=suits; the proper way to change the value of a node inside a node? I think thats where my issue is.

Thanks!

```
struct Card{//card node
    char suit;
    int value;
};

struct BagNode{//bag node
    Card* card;
    BagNode *next;
};

class Bag{
  private:
    BagNode *head, *tail;
  public:
    int size;
    void addCard(char suits, int values){//adds card to end of deck
            BagNode *temp=new BagNode;
            temp->card->suit=suits;
            temp->card->value=values;
            temp->next=head;
            head=temp;
    }

};

int main(){
    Bag deck;
    deck.addCard('H',10);
}
```

Comment: You have to also allocate the `Card`.

Comment: The `card` member variable of `BagNode` is a pointer which you have to manually allocate with `new`. You can do this in the `BagNode` constructor, but make sure you `free` it in the destructor too.

Comment: @Pesho_T Please don't answer in comments

Comment: @CoderCharmander too

Answer (score 1):

When you first create a new BagNode with `BagNode *temp=new BagNode`, you don't initialize the `card` or `next` member variables. Trying to access `temp->card->suits` causes a segfault because you're trying to access a member variable of `card` before the card itself is defined.

Try this:

```c
BagNode *temp=new BagNode;
temp->card = new Card();
temp->card->suit=suits;
temp->card->value=values;
temp->next=head;
head=temp;
```

Comment: I don't think it needs to be dynamically allocated in the first place tbh. Should probably just be a value. Does it make sense for a node to have no value?